# Diagram that compares the power of the t-Test with the power of the Chi-sqare-Test

Tags: r, statistics

I try to compare the power functions of the Chi-square-Test and the t-Test for one particular value and my overall goal was to show that the t-Test is more powerful (because it has an assumption about the distribution). I used the pwr package for R for calculating the power of each function and then wrote two functions and plotted the results. 
However, I do not find that the t-test is better than the Chi-square-test, and I am puzzled by the result. I spend hours on it so every help is so much appreciated.

[image]

Is the code wrong, do I have a wrong understanding of the power functions, or is there something wrong in the package?

```
library(pwr)
#mu is the value for which the power is calculated
#no is the number of observations
#function of the power of the t-test with a h0 of .2
g <- function(mu, alpha, no) { #calculate the power of a particular value for the t-test with h0=.2
      p <- mu-.20
      sigma <- sqrt(.5*(1-.5)) 
      pwr.t.test(n = no, d = p/sigma, sig.level = alpha, type = "one.sample", alternative="greater")$power # d is the effect size p/sigma
}
#chi squared test
h <- function(mu, alpha, no, degree) {#calculate the power of a particular value for the chi squared test
      p01 <- .2 # these constructs the effect size (which is a bit different for the chi squared)
      p02 <- .8

      p11 <-mu
      p12 <- 1-p11

      effect.size <- sqrt(((p01-p11)^2/p01)+((p02-p12)^2/p02)) # effect size

      pwr.chisq.test(N=no, df=degree, sig.level = alpha, w=effect.size)$power
}



#create a diagram
plot(1, 1, type = "n", 
     xlab = expression(mu), 
     xlim = c(.00, .75), 
     ylim = c(0, 1.1), 
     ylab = expression(1-beta), 
     axes=T, main="Power function t-Test and Chi-squared-Test")
      axis(side = 2, at = c(0.05), labels = c(expression(alpha)), las = 3)
      axis(side = 1, at = 3, labels = expression(mu[0]))
      abline(h = c(0.05, 1), lty = 2)

legend(.5,.5, # places a legend at the appropriate place 
c("t-Test","Chi-square-Test"), # puts text in the legend 
lwd=c(2.5,2.5),col=c("black","red"))

curve(h(x, alpha = 0.05, no = 100, degree=1), from = .00, to = .75, add = TRUE, col="red",lwd=c(2.5,2.5) )
curve(g(x, alpha = 0.05, no = 100), from = .00, to = .75, add = TRUE, lwd=c(2.5,2.5))
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem right, you are testing for a Binomial distribution with the mean under the null equal to 0.2 and the alternative being null greater than 0.2? If so, then on line 2 of you function `g`, shouldn't it be `sigma <- sqrt(.2*(1-.2))` instead of `sigma <- sqrt(.5*(1-.5))`? That way, your standard deviation will be smaller, resulting in a larger test statistic and hence smaller p-value leading to higher power.